# transformação de string's no R

Tags: string, r, transações

gostaria de saber se posso transformar uma observação de uma variável, que tem forma de string, em letras maiúsculas.

por exemplo:

```
#como esta:
x=c("Casa branca","Barco Azul","casa preta")
> x
[1] "Casa branca" "Barco Azul"  "casa preta"
#como ficaria:
[1] "CASA BRANCA" "BARCO AZUL"  "CASA PRETA"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x <- c("Casa Branca", "Barco Azul", "Casa Preta")
toupper(x)
[1] "CASA BRANCA" "BARCO AZUL"   "CASA PRETA"
```